# Is "return;" necessary/helpful when using callbacks in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example, are these two effectively the same?

```
someFunction(val, callback){
    callback(val);
};
```

and

```
someFunction(val, callback){
    callback(val);
    return;  // necessary?
};
```

Comment: Note that you can't use the name "var" as a function parameter name since "var" is a keyword (which declares variables)!  You should modify your question and change "var" to "val", or something else to avoid nit picking in the answers =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are the same.  If your function does not return a value then you can either omit the return statement or use it with no argument; in both cases a call to the function returns "undefined".

```javascript
function f1(){};
typeof(f1()); // => "undefined"

function f2(){return;};
typeof(f2()); // => "undefined"
```

Answer (score 9):

While they are the same, you will see something like the following from time to time:

```
someFunction(val, callback){
  if (typeof val != 'object')
    return callback(new Error('val must be an object'));
  callback(null, val);
};
```

In other words, return is used to "break" out of the function early. Most often, I've seen that used with conditionals; you test for an error condition (returning the callback early if there is an error), then avoid having to wrap the remainder of the function in an `else` clause.

Answer (score 1):

In a general JavaScript sense, yes, they're the same - I don't see why node.js would be any different.

In both cases the return value from `someFunction()` will be `undefined`. Whether or not there's a callback within the function is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the fact that you cannot have a formal parameter named `var` your two snippets are identical and working the same way. Every `function` in ECMAscript implicity returns `undefined` if not specified.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same; you should *not* use `return`, because putting it there will be confusing to readers since it is unnecessary.

*sidenote*: In some languages (but probably not javascript) that return statement might not even be executed if tail-call optimizations are enabled (that is, it is reasonable for the compiler to remove the function from the stack once you leave it if you never plan to do anything else). Once again, probably not relevant in any implementation of standard javascript.

Comment: Not true - control flow will pass through the callback function and back into the enclosing function (unless an exception is thrown) until it reaches the "return" statement and exits the function.  So the statement is reachable (i.e. it's not dead code), it just doesn't do anything!

Comment: @maerics: Oops sorry, I've been doing too much advanced callback programming recently. Whether control returns to this functions depends on whether the language semantics allow the use of tail-call optimization of the language stack. I doubt this is the case with javascript, so thank you, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Ah, interesting idea.  Anyway, yes, AFAIK, ECMAScript does not require tail call elimination and I don't think any interpreters do it.